# Bounds of a rotated UIView and Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I have a subclass of UIView which is drawing a location icon. When I rotate the view a few degrees it's bounds (highlighted in green using `CGContextAddRect`) seem to change drastically causing my drawing to look distorted.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bytolution.com](http://bytolution.com/Screenshot%202013.04.09%2016.41.00.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [bytolution.com](http://bytolution.com/Screenshot%202013.04.09%2016.41.43.png))</sub>

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.locationTagView.frame = CGRectMake(40, 80, 240, 240);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(30));
    self.locationTagView.transform = transform;
    [self.view addSubview:self.locationTagView];
}
```

Comment: I've tried `self.locationTagView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;` but it doesn't work. See my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixes it:

```
#define LOCTAG_HEIGHT 240
#define LOCTAG_WIDTH 240

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.locationTagView.frame = CGRectMake(40, 80, LOCTAG_WIDTH, LOCTAG_HEIGHT);
    self.locationTagView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, LOCTAG_WIDTH, LOCTAG_HEIGHT);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(340));
    self.locationTagView.transform = transform;
    [self.view addSubview:self.locationTagView];
}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [bytolution.com](http://bytolution.com/Screenshot%202013.04.09%2021.02.39.png))</sub>

Setting the bounds separately makes it work!